# get method to display containing folder, size, and time of last modification Java

Tags: time, filenames, last-modified

I have a program I am writing for a class. I have got the first part down, but need help with the code for this part:

**containing folder, size, and time of last modification** these steps are the ones I need help writing in.

Here is the challenge
1.  Create a file using any word-processing program or text editor.  Write an application that displays the file’s name, containing folder, size, and time of last modification.

below is my code so far

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import static java.nio.file.AccessMode.*;
public class FileStatistics
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Path filePath =
         Paths.get("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\N Drive\\St Leo Master folder\\COM-209\\module 6\\sixtestfile.txt");
     System.out.println("Path is" + filePath.toString ());
      try
      {
        filePath.getFileSystem().provider().checkAccess
                (filePath, READ, EXECUTE); 
        System.out.println("File can be read & executed");
      }
      catch(IOException e)
      {
          System.out.println("File cannot be used in this app");

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I found my solution, thanks

Comment: BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(filePath, BasicFileAttributes.class); //collects creation time, last modified date & size of file to diplay on screen
        System.out.println("Creation time " + attr.creationTime());
        System.out.println("Last modified time " + attr.lastModifiedTime());
        System.out.println("Size " + attr.size());